# Differences between Watch out! The car is coming and Watch out! The baby is going to fall!

Tags: idioms

> (1) Watch out! The car is coming

> (2) Watch out! The baby is going to fall!

Why in the first one I should use present continuous after watch out and in the second one Going to +V.ing?

Comment: They're awfully similar, but the car is coming now, and the baby is not falling now. *Going to fall* refers to the future.

Comment: Please (in future) include the example sentence in the body of the question, not just in the title. See [Asking Questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4785#4785) from the [*Contributors Guide*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) I will edit to corrct the issue this tiem.

Answer (score 15):

The [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/331569/differences-between-watch-out-the-car-is-coming-and-watch-out-the-baby-is-goin#comment627289_331569) by  
Yosef Baskin is correct. Sentence (1) is using a continuous form because the car is already in the process of coming, while (2) does not because the baby is not yet falling.

If the facts were different, either of the following might be valid:

> (3) Watch out! The car is going to turn left!

> (4)  Watch out! The  baby is falling!

The facts indicate the needed form, because the form helps convey the facts.